# Узнать индекс самого большого элемента

Tags: python, numpy

У меня есть два массива:

```
data = array([10654, 10437, 10604, 10735, 10936, 10279])
index = array([448, 449, 450, 451, 452, 453])
```

Элементы и их индексы, нужно написать программу, которая будет находить индекс большего элемента в `data`.
Нужно ли использовать `pd.Series`? Или можно каким-то другим способом это реализовать?

Comment: Что-то типа `index[data.index(max(data))]`?

Comment: @0andriy, у объекта NDArray нет метода `.index()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

воспользуйтесь методом [NDArray.argmax()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html):

```
In [85]: data = np.array([10654, 10437, 10604, 10735, 10936, 10279])

In [86]: data.argmax()
Out[86]: 4

In [89]: index[data.argmax()]
Out[89]: 452
```

С помощью [pandas.Series.idxmax()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html):

```
In [90]: s = pd.Series(data, index=index)

In [91]: s
Out[91]:
448    10654
449    10437
450    10604
451    10735
452    10936
453    10279
dtype: int32

In [92]: s.idxmax()
Out[92]: 452
```

Comment: В ответе должно быть 451, я должен присвоить имеющиеся индексы к своим элементам. лишь в этом заключается проблема( я знаю про NDArray.argmax()

Comment: @steam-ilka, почему `451` ?? Разве `10604 > 10936`?

Comment: @steam-ilka, если знаете про `NDArray.argmax()`, то почему не используете? ;)

Comment: @MaxU `10936` наверное в комментарии выше

Comment: @MaxU, я использовал, только мне выдавал  индекс "4", дело в том, что не мог понять как присвоить другие индексы(